# How to get .exe program into startup by c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

At first I must say: IT IS NOT KEYLOGER OR ANOTHER VIRUS, I just writing a program to automize some actions on my computer. I know that I must change registry with `IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup(PCWSTR pszAppName)` or `RegOpenKey` with `RegSetValueEx`, or something like this, but I actually don't know how to use it,

so please can someone help me with this problem or someone know another way to get it into startup.

All information that I can say that I on Windows 10, and for example I need to get `someprogram.exe` get into `StartUp` by c++ program

Comment: There are lots of examples that show which settings to write, and how to modify the registry. Please do some more research.

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) and [this](https://genesisdatabase.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/reading-and-writing-registry-in-windows-using-winapi/)

Comment: Creating a registry entry is easier than automating tasks so this feels fishy to me.

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you have to set exe file as startup using C++ code? You can just create shortcut of your exe file. Copy that shortcut to this directory

Easiest way : press win+R and type `shell:startup`. It will open the startup directory right away

Or input the path manually:

- For all users:
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
  Menu\Programs\StartUp
- For current users:
  C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
  Menu\Programs\Startup

After restart the windows and login, your exe file will automatically run. Plus you can check whether your exe file is already registered as startup program using task manager -> startup.

Comment: Don't hard code such paths. Use the known folder API to find the paths.

Comment: No. You need the known folder API.

Answer (score 0):

for first you need to make an method for getting username of any pc, after that save the username in string, after that you can use the path of it.
like this:

```
void get_user_startup()
{
    TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName(username, &username_len);
    wstring usernameWStr(username);
    string usernameStr(usernameWStr.begin(), usernameWStr.end());
    cin.get();
}
```

after you can make using another code for make an copy of exe in startup